# How many codes are possible?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, combinatorics

> The **line - codes** we are looking at **consist of black and red lines**. These lines can have **width 1 or 2**. **Black and red lines are taking turns**, black line, red line, black line, ... The code **ends and begins with a black** line (width 1 or 2). **The width** of the **full code is 14.**

**Question:**

> How many codes are possible ? Give a proof.

**Example:**
[image]

Comment: This is just a normal combinatorics problem. It belongs on math.stackexchange.com, not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $R(n)$ be the number of codes of total width $n$, so the question asks for $R(14)$.

> Consider any code that contains at least $3$ stripes. You can strip off the last two stripes, and still have a valid code that begins and ends in a black stripe, and conversely any valid code can be extended by appending a red and a black stripe to it. The two stripes can be of width $\color{red}{1}+1$, $\color{red}{1}+2$, $\color{red}{2}+1$, or $\color{red}{2}+2$.
>  This means that the $R(n)$ satisfies the recurrence relation:
>  $$R(n)=R(n-2)+2R(n-3)+R(n-4)$$
>  It is fairly obvious that
>  $$R(0)=0\\R(1)=1\\R(2)=1\\R(3)=1\\R(4)=3$$
>  We can simply extend the sequence by applying the recurrence relation:
>  $$0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 11, 17, 27, 45, 72, 116, 189, 305, 493, 799,  ...$$
>  So $R(14)=305$.
>
>  **Some additional maths:** If there were no colours, so that the codes could have any number of stripes, then the sequence would be the Fibonacci numbers. In this case you almost have a Fibonacci sequence too, as each term is at most one away from being the sum of the previous two terms. In fact,
>  $$R(n)=R(n-1)+R(n-2)+c_n$$
>  where $c_n$ is $-1$, $1$, or $0$, when $n$ is $0$, $1$, $2$ modulo $3$ respectively.
>  The ratio of successive terms is the golden ratio, just like Fibonacci. If you look at the associated polynomial, $x^4=x^2+2x+1$, it has the roots $\phi$, $1/\phi$, (like Fibonacci) but also the complex roots $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ which causes those offsets of $-1$, $0$, and $1$.

Comment: Note that the polynomial reduces to (x^2)^2 = (x+1)^2. If the code has n colors in sequence, the characteristic polynomial becomes (x^2)^n = (x+1)^n, providing additional roots.

Answer (score 3):

There are:

> $305$ ways to do this.

Proof:

> Each code belongs to one of the following generating functions.
>  $$\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}$$ $$\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}$$ $$\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}$$ $$\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}\color{red}{(x+x^2)}\color{black}{(x+x^2)}$$

Now:

> Each generating function must contain a certain number of $x^2$ (regardless of color) to hit a code length of $14$. Hence the answer is:
>  $$\binom{7}{7}+\binom{9}{5}+\binom{11}{3}+\binom{13}{1}=1+126+165+13=305$$

Comment: I have an other solution with a little bit more codes.

Comment: 9; 5 = 126 not 105, if you sum that up correctly then you get the same result as Jaap Scherphuis.